# Receive Push Notifications into library project

Tags: android, push-notification, android-library

I have one project as a library to export to lite version of my project. 
In the library project, I have implemented push notifications. I've runthe library project as a normal project and the push notification work fine.
My problem happens when i am importing this project as a library in lite version project.The push notification failed.

Here is my GCMIntentService class:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "206703456431";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        Applications app = (Applications) getApplication();
        app.setDeviceToken(registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message. Extras: " + arg1.getExtras());
        String message = arg1.getExtras().getString("message");
        displayMessage(arg0, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(arg0, message);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.icon_57x57_fixed;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.icon = icon;
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                HomeScreenActivity.class);
        Intent notificationIntentV2 = new Intent(context,
                LoginActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);




    }

    class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
            final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
            return isAppOnForeground(context);
        }

        private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (appProcesses == null) {
                return false;
            }
            final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                        && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The Manifest.xml in library project:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.libraryproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


 <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.myapp.libraryproject" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.myapp.libraryproject.GCMIntentService" />
```

The Manifest.xml in export Lite project (use library project as library):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.liteversion.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                    <category android:name="com.myapp.liteversion" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service android:name="com.myapp.libraryproject.GCMIntentService" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` assumes, by default, that the location of `GCMIntentService` is in the main package of your app, which in your case is `com.myapp.liteversion`. That's why it doesn't find the `GCMIntentService` class, which is actually in `com.myapp.libraryproject.GCMIntentService`.

The solution is to create a sub-class of GCMBroadcastReceiver (and use it in the manifest instead of the base class) and in it to override the following method :

```
protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
    return getDefaultIntentServiceClassName(context);
}
```

to something like :

```
protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
    return GCMIntentService.class.getName();
}
```