# Is it possible for an Android Library to receive push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

Lets assume there exists the following:

- Android App "A"
- Android App "B"
- Android Library "C"
- Server (pushes notifications)

Is it possible for **Library C** to be registered to receive push notifications? In other words, I'd like **App A** and **App B** to use the dependency of **Library C**. I'd like for **App A** and **App B** to both receive push notifications when the **Server** pushes them to **Library C**. I was wondering if this is possible. If so, how?

The reason I ask is because it seems when registering an App with GCM, it must be registered/tied to an "App package name". I was wondering if this works with a "Library package".

Comment: push notification will be received based on application (application_id or manifest package name). so the its related application. what your saying is not possible. Boz application same ids cannot exist

Comment: Register your `Library C` to GCM, and when your `GCMBroadcastReceiver` gets a push notification, you can "forward" it with another pre-defined `Intent` that will be caught by `App A` or `App B` using their own `BroadcastReceivers`

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is possible, but it requires some configuration in the app that uses the library.

If you want your library to receive push messages without the app knowing it, that is however not possible.

> I'd like for App A and App B to both receive push notifications when the Server pushes them to Library C

A server does not send a push to library C, it sends a push to a registration ID (or token). Google doesn't care whether that is tied to an "app" or a "library".

Also [Receive Push Notifications into library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729211/receive-push-notifications-into-library-project) might have useful info for you.